# Tensorflow Object detection: Trained model does not predict ALL instances of the same object in the image

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) to train my custom dataset that contains 2 classes. The network that I use is Faster RCNN + ResNet101 and I utilize the pre-trained model to initialize weights. The training set consists of total 1200 images with class 1 containing 20,000 instances and class 2 containing 6,200 instances. The training seems to work fine - the loss converges well and the mAP on the validation set is ~88%.
However, the prediction results are weird. For example: in an image, if an instance of one class appears multiple times (looking exactly same), the trained model does not predict all the instances in that image. It predicts only a few of them. What can be the reason for such strange behavior?

Due to the imbalance of class instances in the dataset, I augmented class 2 instances so that the number of instances is equal. Even when training with the balanced data, the prediction issue still remains.

I have also tried several combinations of hyperparameters. That doesn't solve the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

The visualization module draws at most 20 boxes on one image by default, you can increase that number by passing `max_boxes_to_draw` to the visualization function.

If that is not the issue, have you tried increasing the number of proposals? It appears that you have ~20 objects per image on average which is more that the average number of objects in images of, say, COCO dataset.

Comment: I have set `max_boxes_to_draw` to `None`, so it draws all the predicted boxes. The issue is with the trained model itself.

Comment: Added another suggestion to my answer.